# MATCH/DELETE requests stopped working after adding Spring Security dependency(some time after)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In Spring application (java) all controllers worked fine (take \ add \ modify \ delete, i.e. GET \ POST \ PATCH \ DELETE requests), however after adding the Spring Security dependency at some point the DELETE and PATCH methods stopped working ... In this case, the GET \ POST methods work properly for all controllers. When trying to access the PATCH \ DELETE methods in the console, it gives the following error

`WARN 15516 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]`

At the same time, on the web link for this (any PATCH/DELETE) request, it gives the following result

[Web view of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWDwv.png)

If it is important I can send the code of the rewritten **configure** method (HttpSecurity http). Also, perhaps importantly, controllers are implemented using @Controller annotations and not @RestController. Can you please tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: You can bisect your commits and see exactly where things stopped working.

Comment: Sadly, I was adding Security (authorization/registration) part without any tests in the main (not authorization related) database,and also got no any backups of earlier version of application (except the app without any Security implementation at all, that is working properly with those requests).

Comment: Hi [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15262852/nick-alymov): It can be helpful providing the rewritten configure method (HttpSecurity http).

Comment: @Meziane
Here it is https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/3vl8, there's a text form of my configure

Comment: Hi [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15262852/nick-alymov), you have solved the problem yourself. That very good. Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem, the thing is that i was running app with @SpringBootApplication annotation like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RunningApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RunningApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

So basically, before I was running app with Tomcat server, and got other config with missing thing, that was **hiddenHttpMethodFilter** , so now i've added this bean (to my running app class - RunningApplication), and after that all methods worked properly

```
@Bean
    HiddenHttpMethodFilter hiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
        return new HiddenHttpMethodFilter();
    }
```